# How to fix writing a list content in a file

Tags: haskell

I have a function which contains a list. I want just to write that list content in a file from main after user input.

```
putTodo :: (Int, String) -> IO ()
putTodo (n, todo) = putStrLn (show n ++ ": " ++ todo)

prompt :: [String] -> IO ()
prompt todos = do
    putStrLn "The list contains:"
    mapM_ putTodo (zip [0..] todos)
    putStrLn " "
    command <- getLine
    getCommand command todos
```

What I tried:

```
main = do
          outh <- openFile "agenda.txt" WriteMode;
          hPutStrLn outh prompt[]

          -- hPutStrLn outh (show prompt[])
          -- hPrint (show prompt[])
          hClose outh;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should include the error(s) you're getting in your question – they are often very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains a couple of errors / problems:

- `prompt[]` isn't valid (in `main`) - this should be `prompt`
- `hPutStrLn` expects a `String` as its second argument, but you provide `IO()`
- `getCommand` is not defined

What you need is:

- a list of todos (possibly returned by a function)
- a function that converts this list of todos to a string
- `hPutStrLn` to print this string to the output file

Here's a simple version with a hard-coded list of todos (my Haskell isn't very advanced, so this could probably be done in a much more elegant way):

```
import System.IO

type Todo = (Int, String)

todoToString :: Todo -> String
todoToString (idx, name) = (show idx) ++ " : " ++ name

todosToString :: [Todo] -> String
todosToString todos = foldl (\acc t -> acc ++ "\n" ++ (todoToString t)) "" todos 

allTodos :: [Todo]
allTodos = [(1, "Buy milk"), (2, "Program Haskell")]

main = do
  outh <- openFile "agenda.txt" WriteMode;
  hPutStrLn outh (todosToString allTodos);
  hClose outh;
```